# Cannot correctly position an input element with CSS

Tags: css, html, input

I have a form that is being filled with dynamically generated dropdowns.

I have set the display property to 'table' on advice in order to keep the container centered even as the elements are added.

The problem I have is that I'm using an input type=image instead of a button to submit the form and this image will not stay in the container when the dynamic dropdowns area added. As soon as the a single dropdown is added the width increase in the div containing the form pushed the 'button' down onto the next line, while I want to keep it inline.

ps I have tried adding display: inline but this isnt working.

```
<div id="searchBar">
<div id="searchwrapper">    
            <form name="search_input">
        I am looking for a      
    <div id="sBar1" style="display:inline;">
    <select id="search_level" class="selectSearchBar" name="search_level">  
    <?php
        echo "<option>Level</option>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_level, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                echo "<option value=".$row['id'].">".$row['level']."</option>";
                }
            ?>              
                </select>
                    </div>
    <div id="sBar2" class="selectSearchBar"></div>
    <div id="sBar3" class="selectSearchBar"></div>
    tutor in <input type=text class="searchbox" id="location"  value="Location"/> 
    <input type=image src="images/search_icon.png "  class="searchbox_submit" name="searchbox_submit"  onclick="searchLocations()" value=""></form>
            </div>
</div>
```

and the corresponding CSS:

```
#searchBar{
width:940;
margin: 0px auto;
}


#searchwrapper{
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
min-width:600px;
padding-top: 10px;
background: red;
}


#searchwrapper form {

}

.searchbox {
border:0px; /*important*/
background-color:transparent; /*important*/ 
position:absolute; /*important*/
width:200px;
height:40px;
border-radius:9px;
font-size: inherit;
}

.searchbox_submit {
border:0px; /*important*/
background-color:transparent; /*important*/
position:absolute; /*important*/
}
.selectSearchBar{
    height:40px;
    width:137px;
    display:inline;
    background-image: url('../images/up_down_arrows.png');
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    margin:3px 1px 0px 0px;
    border-radius:9px;
}
```

This image is what I want i.e. the icon at the end of the row
[image: This image shows the icon in the correct position (it's too far up but it appears at the end of the div as I need it)]

this is the problem after each select is added dynamically:
[image: This is what happens after I add a new select]

Comment: You have several `select` elements on your page.  How are they supposed to be positioned? vertically like a list or horizontally with each following one another?  Also, what are the pixel dimensions of your button-image?

Comment: It would be helpful to add a screenshot of how it's currently rendering, and an image mock-up or description of what it should be doing differently. Also, it may be important to see the CSS for `.selectSearchBar`.

Comment: @Marc Audet - the button image is 24 x 21 px - the scrollbars are horizontally aligned and appearing one after another

Answer (score 0):

If I were doing this, I would start with the following HTML:

```
<div id="searchBar">
    <div id="searchwrapper">
        <form name="search_input">I am looking for a
            <div id="sBar1" class="selectSearchBar">
                <select id="search_level1" class="selectSearchBar" name="search_level">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="sBar2" class="selectSearchBar">
                <select id="search_level2" class="selectSearchBar" name="search_level">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div id="sBar3" class="selectSearchBar">
                <select id="search_level3" class="selectSearchBar" name="search_level">
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                </select>
            </div>tutor in
            <input type=text class="searchbox" id="location" value="Location" />
            <input type=image src="http://placehold.it/20x20 " class="searchbox_submit" name="searchbox_submit" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

On your select elements, make sure the `id` values are unique.

For the CSS:

```css
#searchBar {
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    text-align: center;
}
#searchwrapper {
    min-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
#searchwrapper form {
}
div.selectSearchBar {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
select.selectSearchBar {
    width: 137px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.searchbox {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-size: inherit;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.searchbox_submit {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See working demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Kjby6/

**How This Works**

The strategy is to keep all the elements in a single line, so you want to use either floats or inline-blocks or inline elements.

Let's start with the two simplest elements, `.searchbox` and `.searchbox_submit`, both of with are inline `input` elements, so no need to do anything, except adjust the vertical positioning with `vertical-align: middle` (my choice, but please adjust as you see fit).

The `div.selectSearchBar` is a block level element by default, so set `display: inline-block` and `vertical-align: middle`.

For the `select.selectSearchBar`, specify the height and border radius and use `display: inline-block` in case you want to add margins or padding or whatever you may need for styling.

Now, all your elements sit a horizontal line and are use `vertically-align: middle` to place your input elements with respect to the inline text.

These elements are enclosed by `#searchwrapper`, so I want this box to shrink-to-fit the content so use `display: inline-block`, add padding for visual formatting.

Finally, to center `#searchwrapper`, use `text-align: center` for the `#searchBar` parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the width of the main container, #searchBar (currently 940px) or decrease the width of the "Location" input field just enough so that there is room left for the search icon / submit button. The issue is that the current width isn't enough to fit everything on one line after the additional select dropdown is added.

You can easily decrease the width of the "Location" input since there is a lot of blank space that the text doesn't fill.